# Why is `getcontext().prec = 50` not changing the length of the variable `a` using Decimal in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

## The code

I have been testing out Decimal in Python3, and I have come across some strange things that did not make any sense to me.

First of all, I imported Decimal

```
from decimal import *
```

Next, I set to what accuracy (in digits) I want any calculations to be

```
getcontext().prec = 50
```

Then, I defined and printed a variable called `num`, which was equal to 0.6 recurring

```
num = Decimal(2/3)
```

However, when I try and print `num` I get this

```
print(num)
0.66666666666666662965923251249478198587894439697265625
```

Also, changing to either of these:

```
getcontext().prec = 500
getcontext().prec = 3
```

Changes nothing, even as 3 it gives the same output

## My main two questions

So theres two things that I don't understand with this

1. Why the random and incorrect digits after the first `0.6666666666666666`? I was expecting it to say `0.6` with as many `6's` as the number defined in the `getcontext().prec`
2. Isn't `getcontext().prec = 3` supposed to make it 3 digits long? Because its still doing a lot more than that, and `getcontext().prec = 500` also doesn't make it anywhere near 500 digits long

**Edit:**

I am using Python3 on Windows

Comment: You perform the division using floating point numbers, not decimals. Also depending on rounding in use you'd see a lot 6's followed by a 7.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Floating point can't do 500 decimal places, it is limited to 16. I need to be very accurate in my program and therefore found Decimal to do that (go beyond the original 16 decimal places)

Comment: Putting aside [how floating point math works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), it'd seem you expect that `Decimal(2/3)` somehow performs the division using `Decimal` values, which it does not. In Python 3 `2/3` is performed using floating point math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're converting the result of division 2/3, which is a *IEEE 754 double-precision floating point approximation* of the result of 2/3, i.e. 0.6666... into `Decimal`. Divide a *`Decimal`* by another, say, and you get

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 50
>>> Decimal(2) / Decimal(3)
Decimal('0.66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667')
```

---

However these are still approximations. If you're dealing with fractions only (just doing arithmetic), use `fractions.Fraction`:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> fractions.Fraction('2') / 3
Fraction(2, 3)
>>> str(_)
2/3
```

Comment: So should I use fractions if I'm using **Really** large numbers?

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld no. You'd use fractions when you need to do arithmetic on rational numbers.

Comment: `num = 45104594 / 163406212964819471983779 ` So if I'm doing that, but with around a billion calculations like this in a row, should I use fractions or a decimal number to a million decimal places or so

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld It depends on what you're doing. Everything depends. You could even use floats. You didn't tell *anything* about your use case beyond that you're doing divisions.

Comment: How about you go and use your intuition and ask only when you meet another problem.